# TimescaleDB: how to ingest files from s3?

Tags: amazon-s3, timescaledb, data-ingestion

In Postgres, a way to ingest files from s3 directly is through the `aws_s3` extension, using `table_import_from_s3` function for example.

However this is not directly supported by TimescaleDB as of now.

```
=> CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS aws_s3 CASCADE; 
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/14/extension/aws_s3.control": No such file or directory
```

Is there an alternative to ingest data from s3 files directly into TimescaleDB?